# using IF to see a directory exists if not do something

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to move the directories from $DIR1 to $DIR2 if $DIR2 does not have the same directory name

`if [[ ! $(ls -d /$DIR2/* | grep test) ]]` is what I currently have.
`then
     mv $DIR1/test* /$DIR2
 fi`

first it gives

```
ls: cannot access //data/lims/PROCESSING/*: No such file or directory
```

when $DIR2 is empty

however, it still works.

secondly
when i run the shell script twice.
it doesn't let me move the directories with the similar name.

for example
in $DIR1  i have test-1 test-2 test-3 
when it runs for the first time all three directories moves to $DIR2 
after that i do mkdir test-4 at $DIR1 and run the script again..
it does not let me move the test-4 because my loop thinks that test-4 is already there since I am grabbing all test

how can I go around and move test-4 ?

Comment: Is this two separate questions? If so, could you post them as separate questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can check whether or not a directory exists using bash's built in 'True if directory exists' expression:

```
test="/some/path/maybe"
if [ -d "$test" ]; then
    echo "$test is a directory"
fi
```

However, you want to test if something is not a directory. You've shown in your code that you already know how to negate the expression:

```
test="/some/path/maybe"
if [ ! -d "$test" ]; then
    echo "$test is NOT a directory"
fi
```

You also seem to be using `ls` to get a list of files. Perhaps you want to loop over them and do something if the files are not a directory?

```
dir="/some/path/maybe"
for test in $(ls $dir);
do
    if [ ! -d $test ]; then
        echo "$test is NOT a directory."
    fi
done
```

A good place to look for bash stuff like this is Machtelt Garrels' guide. [His page on the various expressions you can use in if statements](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) helped me a lot.

**Moving directories from a source to a destination if they don't already exist in the destination:**

For the sake of readability I'm going to refer to your `DIR1` and `DIR2` as `src` and `dest`. First, let's declare them:

```
src="/place/dir1/"
dest="/place/dir2/"
```

Note the trailing slashes. We'll append the names of folders to these paths so the trailing slashes make that simpler. You also seem to be limiting the directories you want to move by whether or not they have the word `test` in their name:

```
filter="test"
```

So, let's first loop through the directories in `source` that pass the `filter`; if they don't exist in `dest` let's move them there:

```
for dir in $(ls -d $src | grep $filter); do
    if [ ! -d "$dest$dir" ]; then
        mv "$src$dir" "$dest"
    fi
done
```

I hope that solves your issue. But be warned, @gniourf_gniourf posted a link in the comments that should be heeded!

Comment: I edit the question. Hope this helps your understanding

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thank you, that's a great link - good to learn something new :-)

Comment: Still can't find the solution. i used your coding as will but this coding doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Young Try changing the `mv` command to and `echo` and see what it's trying to do.

Comment: i also did that before commenting... but it doesn't echo anything back... I am currently playing around with you code to see if I can find something

Comment: try putting an `echo "source = $src and dest = $dest"` before the for loop. Then, before the if statement, an `echo trying $dir`

Comment: just found some solution using your coding.. I just had to take $src out of mv and $dir next to $dest at mv

Comment: Yes, changing `$dest$dir` to `$dest` makes sense. I'm surprised about the `$src`. Did you put trailing slashes when you declared `$src` and `$dest`?

Comment: yes I tried few things including that.. what that $src do is create a directory with a test1 and put original test1 into it.. so it wasn't necessary... thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72275/discussion-between-dsclose-and-young).

Comment: wait... I just found one error.. When i run this, it works fine.. but when I create a directory that contains the same name which is already in $dest  at $src and runs it again.. it should fail and go out of if loop but it still goes into the if loop

Comment: Based on your previous comments, check the output of `echo "$src$dir and $dest$dir"` in the for loop. Also, consider @idobr's rather elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to mv some directories to another according to some pattern, than you can use find:

```
find . -type d -name "test*" -exec mv -t /tmp/target {} +
```

> Details:
>
> -type d - will search only for directories
>
> -name "" - set search pattern
>
> -exec - do something with find results
>
> -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY

There are many examples of exec or xargs usage.

And if you do not want to overwrite files, than add -n option to mv command:

```
find . -type d -name "test*" -exec mv -n -t /tmp/target {} +
```

> -n, --no-clobber do not overwrite an existing file